# Centos 5.5 on Hyper-V 2016

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, hyper-v, boot

I'm trying to install Centos 5.5 on Hyper-V 2016. The installation process passes correctly but when I try to boot newly installed system it stuck at the beginning. The only thing I can see is black screen with blinking underscore sign. It doesn't respond to keyboard. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an old version of CentOS 5?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason ;) I can't use diffrent version.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 5 / CentOS 5 [cannot boot with UEFI](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/42632), but Hyper-V 2016 creates Generation 2 virtual machines by default. These always boot with UEFI only.

To install CentOS 5, you will need to create the virtual machine as a Generation 1 virtual machine.

**WARNING: CentOS 5 is past end of life. You should upgrade to a supported OS distribution immediately.**

Comment: This is akin to asking how one can install Windows 98 on a new server. I understand requirements and not having control of your environment, but this is where the OP should push back at whoever is making this request.

Comment: That's not the issue. I've tried both generations and both disk types.

Comment: You should provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

There were docker images available that contained centos5, so there is a chance you'll dig up 5.5 somewhere on the Internet.

The docker daemon should run on a recent Linux. CentOS 7 is a minumum, although Ubuntu or Debian will have a much more useful docker version. All these systems run on Hyper-V 2016 either BIOS or UEFI.